# Bootstrap responsive height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a website and I'm making a register form, but I need to adjust div height's according to wiewport, something like this:

xs devices: 12
sm devices: 9
md devices: 7

Note: I'm using bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
   div{
       height: 12px;
   }
}
```

You can use [this website](http://viewportsizes.com/) to find the viewport sizes for multiple devices and you replace the max-width by the size you want.

The media query will check for your screen size and applies the directives inside the block if the condition is true.

[More about media queries here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)  and [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)